# Populating a table from another table using ColdFusion with data from two different rows

Tags: sql-server-2005, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, sql-insert

```
date                       timeIn                     timeOut  userID    userName
2013-10-23 00:00:00.000    2013-10-23 13:19:32.000    NULL     1         SANDEEP KAUL
2013-10-23 00:00:00.000    2013-10-23 21:36:35.000    NULL     1         SANDEEP KAUL
2013-10-23 00:00:00.000    2013-10-23 12:44:38.000    NULL     2         KASHIF RAZI
2013-10-23 00:00:00.000    2013-10-23 21:15:48.000    NULL     2         KASHIF RAZI
```

Thing is for the same user name there are two entries and in the second entry for the same user name I want to insert the `timeIn` value in the `timeOut` column in another table. So that I can make one record having `date, timeIn, timeOut, userID, userName`.

I am using SQL Server 2005 and ColdFusion 8. I want to write the logic for this in the ColdFusion language.

Comment: *So that I can make one record* I am a little confused about what you are trying to do, and which part you are struggling with. Can you elaborate on what you have tried? Also, using the data above what should this combined record look like?

Comment: The only ColdFusion part of this is that your query will be inside cfquery tags.  The logic will be done with sql.  Having said that, your question is not clear.  You say you want to insert the 2nd record.  What is that based on?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Max(timeIn)
WHERE UserId=2
```

This will give you the entry with the most recent timeIn value for that specific user to put into another table.